# How to trim a group of mp3 files with a specific timings

Tags: windows, audio, mp3, editing, digital-audio

I am having trouble finding the way to trim bunch of mp3 files. The time from the beginning and time from the end is fixed across all the files and should be specified by the user.

I already tried Audacity (Chains mode), but it doesn't have a command for trimming.
Also, I tried [mpTrim](http://www.mptrim.com/), but it allows to specify timings only when processing one file.

What are other options for achieving this goal?

Comment: This is off topic as it is asking for a software suggestion and is a "shopping" question.  It will likely be closed.

Comment: The question may be able to be saved if you tweak it just about general ways to accomplish this, rather than looking for "tools" and the like. Then it may be a suitable question for the format at SU. Definitely keep what you have tried involved as well.

Comment: Speaking of mpTrim, the Pro version seems to have batch support.

Answer (score 2):

[**Mp3Splt**](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net) (FOSS) has a batch mode and should be able to do what you want:

[image: 1]

Otherwise you can use a batch file to loop through all your files and trim them using **ffmpeg** [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390731).